# Magento 2 - How to create attribute with images on product page

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to recreate this in magento 2:
[image]

It's an image slider with attribute icons. 
I currently have it in magento 1 as a multiple select value:
[image]

This is the Magento 1 code:

```
<?php if ($multiSelectArray = $this->getProduct ()->getAttributeText('care_instructions')) : ?>
<div class="main-container col1-layout guides-wrap">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="col-main">
            <div id="care-instructions">
                <?php
                    if (is_string($multiSelectArray)) {
                        $multiSelectArray = array($multiSelectArray);
                    }

                    foreach ($multiSelectArray as $multiSelectItem):

                        $multiSelectItemImage = str_replace(" ", "_", $multiSelectItem);

                        ?>
                        <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media'); ?>wysiwyg/careinstructions/<?php echo $multiSelectItemImage ?>.jpg" /><span><?php echo $multiSelectItem ?></span></div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How do I assign the images to the attributes? Will the above code work in Magento 2?